# IntelliJ Quick switch to multiple Git branches

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have two modules with each having different branches (Dev and Release). Whenever I need to switch between dev and release branches, I need to checkout each modules related branches individually.

Example;

Profile 1: Module1 (dev_m1) , Module2 (dev_m1)

Profile 2: Module1 (release_m1), Module2 (release_m2)

Is there quick a way to switch to a set of branches of my choice, like switching from profile 1 to profile 2 as in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there quick a way to switch to a set of branches of my choice?

No, there is no such option.

[This](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177729) feature request may be convenient for you, please vote for it.

There is a "Synchronous branch control" feature:
When you invoke Git Branches for the first time, IDEA looks at the repositories registered in the project, and if they all are on branches with same names, proposes to control branches synchronously. See [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/08/git-branches-for-multi-root-projects/) for more